# Extract second character from string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column that holds certain values where I would like to extract the second string after the hyphen and keep the original.

**Data**

```
   type            stat
   SSS-AA-11111    y
   FFF-BB-22222    y
```

**Desired**

```
type            type1 stat
SSS-AA-11111    AA    y
FFF-BB-22222    BB    y
```

**Doing**

```
  df[['type', 'type1']] = df['type'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)`
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split` and keep the second element with `str[1]`:

```
df['type1'] = df['type'].str.split('-').str[1]
print(df)

# Output
           type stat type1
0  SSS-AA-11111    y    AA
1  FFF-BB-22222    y    BB
```